# How to limit concurrent users in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I need to limit number of users that are logging in to my web app using weblogic.

Found solution is oracle documents "The weblogic.http.session.maxConcurrentRequest property limits the number of concurrent requests for a session. If the number of concurrent requests for a given session exceeds the specified value, the servlet container will start rejecting requests. By default, this property is set to -1, which indicates the servlet container does not impose any restrictions."

But no idea where or how to set this settings.

need to throw error message that user should only be logged 1 session at a time or kill the old session.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as JAVA_OPTION in your domain's startup script.